# How to connect a device to a SDK?

Tags: android

I am currently working on a web app dashboard interface, the interface is basically a QA debugging tool, that will allow it's users to run playtest sessions. On my understanding terms, the dashboard connects/registers a game through an SDK key. the SDK key origins are generated in the web app and are used on a panel on Unity that our devs created and it successfully links a game to the web app interface.

I want to include a feature which will enable a user to connect their smartphone or tablet to their user profile in the web app...

**Q.** How do you connect a device,(a mobile device or a tablet) to the Web app, how do I get a user to register its device on their user profile and which informations should I provide and/or ask a user in order to do so?

**notes:**

1- I am not a developer, I am a UX Designer, I remembered this website which helped me in the past with some front-end questions and the devs at work are currently unavailable to answer to my endless questions. so I am doing this of my own volition.

2- On my understanding terms, I know that a device is linked via its device ID, which changes from app to app.

3 - if my question is not eligible for this site, please at least refer me to a better source. thank you in advance!

**Thank you all !**

Comment: You have some concepts screwed up that make it difficult to guess what you're really asking.  An SDK is a library of functions/classes.  You wouldn't connect a device on it.  Its called by your app.

Comment: oh, i'll edit my question in that case

Comment: @GabeSechan, can you read it now? if you can't help me please at least refer me to a better source, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a tool to connect to this SDK (is this the Unity SDK?) and create fake game session data.
If that's the case, you'd use the SDK just like the actual game would. The only difference is that you don't want your QA tool getting its own id, but use the id of the game apk on the device? If this is indeed what you need to do the following methods should help:

- Method 1: You're sharing various bits and pieces of data between the game and the QA tool

  - Set up a special permission in the actual game with the `protectionLevel` = `signature` (e.g. `com.somegame.android.permission.PRIVATE_ACCESS`). This [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/permission-element) on *permissions* should be useful
  - Have a `BroadcastReceiver`, `ContentProvider`, or `Service` in the main game that requires the above permission (Exactly which one you'd use depends on how much data you're sharing).
  - The QA tool declares a `uses-permission` element in it's manifest with the permission stated above
  - Sign both the QA Tool and the Game APK with the same keys
  - The QA tool and the actual game can now communicate with each other through the means you've provided above
  - The advantage this method has over the next is that even if you haven't run the game before, the QA tool can trigger the registration process in the game and get the id, without requiring you to actually ever run the game.
- Method 2: All you need is the `ID`

  - Specify the same `sharedUserId` in both the actual game and the QA tool's manifest (see [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#uid) for documentation)
  - Once the game acquires its id, it writes it to its `SharedPreferences` (preferrably a named preference file as opposed to the default)
  - The QA tool can now read the preference file (be sure to use the same name) and obtain the ID. The drawback here is that the game must have run before and saved its id in order for the QA tool to access it.
- Method 3: If your game runs in a webview

  - Use a [Javascript interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#BindingJavaScript) to obtain the info from the webview
- Method 4: If your game runs on the web

  - Directly use the game APIs to access the id. [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) would be a great tool in implementing your API calls.

The wording in your question makes it rather difficult to exactly understand what your goal is. I suggest you consult with your dev to come up with a better problem description.

Best of luck.

Comment: the devs are developing the A.I. to run real game session data, it's a very interesting project.